# Spider for parsing JSON in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have been using scrapy for some time now and I wish to know what is the best way to parse JSON. There are specially designed spiders for XML and CSV in scrapy viz. `XMLFeedSpider` and `CSVFeedSpider`. Is there any such spider for JSON too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default JSON parser for Scrapy, but you can use the `json` module to parse your response and convert it to items:

```
jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
```

However if you plan to write a general solution like `CSVFeedSpider` feel free to contribute it to the Scrapy project but I guess `json.loads` does the trick of consuming JSON responses.

Comment: Yes, it does the job well. But I was just wondering if there was a built in solution too. Thanks anyway!